# Mostrando erros de validação no formulário de contato

Tags: php

Tenho este formulário de contato e gostaria que fosse mostrado todos os erros de validação quando tiver, por exemplo, se deixar o campo de nome e e-mail sem preencher, quando desse o submit retornasse esses dois erros, no código atual só mostra um erro, mesmo que tenha outros, já procurei vários códigos na internet e não consegui resolver isso, alguém pode me ajudar?

**style.css**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  color: #333;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
.formulario {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
/* FF 4-18 */

input:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
/* FF 19+ */

input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
/* IE 10+ */

textarea:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
textarea:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
/* FF 4-18 */

textarea:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
/* FF 19+ */

textarea:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
/* IE 10+ */

.nome,
.email,
.telefone,
.assunto {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #777;
}
.email,
.assunto {
  float: right;
}
.formulario .mensagem {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #777;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.formulario .enviar {
  background: #58D68D;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.formulario .enviar:hover {
  background: #2ECC71;
}
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="formulario" action="enviar.php" method="POST">
    <input class="nome" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
    <input class="email" type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" />
    <input class="telefone" type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" />
    <input class="assunto" type="text" name="assunto" placeholder="Assunto" />
    <textarea class="mensagem" name="mensagem" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"></textarea>
    <input class="enviar" name="enviar_email" type="submit" value="Enviar Dados" />
  </form>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**enviar.php**

```
require_once 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';
if (isset($_POST['enviar_email'])):
$nome = strip_tags(trim($_POST['nome']));
$email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
$telefone = strip_tags(trim($_POST['telefone']));
$assunto = strip_tags(trim($_POST['assunto']));
$mensagem = strip_tags(trim($_POST['mensagem']));
$erro = array();
if (empty($nome)):
    $erro[] = "Digite seu nome";
elseif (empty($email)):
    $erro[] = "Digite um email";
elseif (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)):
    $erro[] = "E-Mail invalido";
elseif (empty($telefone)):
    $erro[] = "Digite seu telefone";
elseif (empty($assunto)):
    $erro[] = "Digite um assunto";
elseif (empty($mensagem)):
    $erro[] = "Digite uma mensagem";
else:
    $Email = new PHPMailer();
    $Email->setLanguage('br');

    $host = '';
    $username = '';
    $senha = '';
    $porta = '';
    $secure = '';

    $receber_email = 'sergiojfjfjf@gmail.com';
    $receber_nome = 'Sérgio Machado';

    $from = $username;
    $fromName = 'Sérgio';

    $Email->isSMTP();
    $Email->Host = $host;
    $Email->SMTPAuth = true;
    $Email->Username = $username;
    $Email->Password = $senha;
    $Email->Port = $porta;
    $Email->SMTPSecure = $secure;

    $Email->From = $from;
    $Email->FromName = $fromName;
    $Email->addReplyTo($email, $nome);
    $Email->addAddress($receber_email, $receber_nome);

    $Email->isHTML(true);
    $Email->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $Email->WordWrap = 70;

    $Email->Subject = $assunto; //Assunto
    $Email->Body = $mensagem;

    $enviado = $Email->send();
    if ($enviado) {
        echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso';
    } else {
        echo 'Error: ' . $Email->ErrorInfo;
    }
endif;
endif;

foreach ($erro as $err) {
if (!empty($err)):
    echo $err;
endif;
}
?>
```

Comment: Opa @Miguel resolveu sim cara, eu não sei o que houve, marquei novamente, muito obrigado, agora eu coloquei o ajax e ficou massa, mas to vendo algumas pessoas abaixo dizer que não é recomendado usar tantos ifs

Comment: De nada @Sergio Não se preocupe, não tem importância nem faz mal usar os if que forem precisos.... O unico senão em usar 9999 ifs é que o código fica muito extenso... De resto se estiverem bem estruturados não há qualquer senão. Entretanto esteja à vontade para escolher qualquer uma soluções em baixo

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente @Miguel, uma coisa bem simples que resolveu meu problema, acho fantástico essa colaboração das pessoas em se ajudarem. nesse mesmo formulário eu acrescentei o campo de imagem e sempre que dou submit retorna um erro de PHP eu não se se é o ajax que esta interferindo.

Comment: Sem ver não sei. O melhor a fazer é colocar outra questão com código relevante e explicar o problema. Eu e outros colegas tentamos ajuda-lo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema está nas condições, como estão envoltas em `else if(...` a partir do momento que entra numa já não vai entrar na proxima, mesmo que seja verdade. Faça assim:

```
$erro = array();
if (empty($nome)) {
    $erro[] = "Digite seu nome";
}
if (empty($email)){
    $erro[] = "Digite um email";
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $erro[] = "E-Mail invalido";
}
if (empty($telefone)) {
    $erro[] = "Digite seu telefone";
}
if (empty($assunto)) {
    $erro[] = "Digite um assunto";
}
if (empty($mensagem)) {
    $erro[] = "Digite uma mensagem";
}
if(count($erro) < 1) {
    // Mandar email, está tudo bem, não há nada no array $erro
}
else {
    foreach ($erro as $err) {
        echo $err. '<br>';
    }
}
```

Outra maneira de fazer:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar_email'])) {

    $required = array( // as keys têm de ser as mesmas do array $_POST
        'nome' => 'Digite seu nome',
        'telefone' => 'Digite seu telefone',
        'assunto' => 'Digite um assun',
        'mensagem' => 'Digite uma mensagem'
    );

    $erro = array();
    $inputs = array();
    foreach($required as $key => $err_msg) {
        if(empty($_POST[$key])) {
            $erro[] = $err_msg;
        }
        else {
            $inputs[$key] = strip_tags(trim($_POST[$key]));
        }
    }
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // isto só por si já verifica se o email está vazio, e se é valido (não vale a pena strip_tags, trim)
        $erro[] = "E-Mail invalido";
    }
    if(count($erro) > 0) {
        foreach ($erro as $err) {
            echo $err. '<br>';
        }
    }

    else {

        // envio de email, alterar estes campos:
        $Email->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $inputs['nome']);
        $Email->Subject = $inputs['assunto'];
        $Email->Body = $inputs['mensagem'];
    }
}
```

Comment: pode até funcionar, mas não é recomendável usar tantos ifs assim... você não acha?

Comment: Porque não? Podia fazer-se um `foreach(..` para percorrer os inputs e para ver ver se estão vazios, neste caso o unico que difere é o email... Mas note que ia fazer exatamente o mesmo numero de verificações... Ou seja, em termos de performance era igual, e de legibilidade e adequação ao código do colega esta solução parece-me adequada... E lembre-se que existe uma mensagem costumizada para cada `input` que esteja vazio, não havia muita volta a dar neste caso.... A unica ventagem seria mesmo a redução de linhas codigo à custa da legibilidade para o colega que fez a pergunta

Comment: não vou reclamar, agora se aparecer um maneira melhor de fazer isso seria ótimo!

Comment: Não é melhor vamos ter de ter o trabalho de estar a pôr os inputs no array por outro lado. Mas vou fazer. Tenha em mente que não é melhor. É só diferente

Comment: Feito @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira, tem aqui outra maneira de fazer

Comment: se tem outra maneira de fazer,  tem sim! até por que o PHP permite fazer de diversas formas, mas você já colocou de duas formas então acho suficiente, vou fazer de uma maneira mais simples e fico devendo uma resposta... ok?!

Comment: Eu não estava a perguntar se tinha, estava a dizer que tem aí em cima outra maneira. Com a mesma funcionalidade exatamente. Também quero saber, estou sempre disposto a aprender.  Obgado. Claro que há infinitas maneiras de fazer @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira, eu sei perfeitamente que não tenho exclusividade nas maneiras de fazer validações em forms, lol cada um faz à sua maneira, umas melhores outras piores, umas diferentes outras iguais

Comment: sim agora que entendi, e você é de Portugal? vi pelo se português "tem aqui outra maneira de fazer" entendi se havia outro jeito de fazer -> foi essa a confusão no idioma só isso!

Comment: Sim sou, sem problema @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira